does not go inside : const { isLoading, error, data } = useQuery(["user"] ---> in react
does not go inside the below method when click on Profile .
Can someone help me with this ?
const { isLoading, error, data } = useQuery(["user"], () =>    
    makeRequest.get("/users/find/"+ userId).then((res) => {
      console.log("inside-----client/src/pages/profile/Profile.jsx");
      return res.data;

    })
  );


you need to share what the error is.  "Something went wrong" is what you display when the "error" value is truthy, not the value of "error".
you could add this line to view the error: useEffect(() => { if (error) { console.error(error); } }, [error]);
